# How to set up a different download folder for every single Slack channel?

Tags: slack

I'm looking for a way to have a separate download folder for each Slack channel.

Slack official app doesn't give this opportunity, and devs aren't looking to implement it.

Any idea on how to setup something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. I also tried same before. but in reality you can't do this.

```
A quick heck around is use shortcake naming culture. For example if you have folder for codebase you can name folder as cd_1, cd_2, cd_3. For server folders name as ser_1, ser_2, ser_3.
```

So by doing this you can get benefit of folder sorting. All same folder will be visible at same location.